# Angular 6: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a weird error, at my application the prevents me from moving forward.
I have a variable of type `any[]`, which using me as a data source of a table:

```
<table mat-table  [dataSource]="EcoSummaryList">
```

the variable is initialized into an empty array. But when I'm trying even to assign something into the array, I'm getting the following error:

> core.js:12632 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'EcoSummaryList' of
>   undefined at
>   push../src/app/eco-summary/eco-summary.component.ts.EcoSummaryComponent.OnSummaryLoad

Here's the relevant code:

```
public EcoSummaryList: any[] = [];

OnSummaryLoad(data: any) {
  this.EcoSummaryList = [];
  console.log(data);

  if (data == undefined || data == null) return;
  this.EcoSummaryList = data;

}
```

The data object is all right, and the data is coming all right and it used to work in the past.

I tried to look at other posts to find the answer without any success and I also tried to initialize the array at the constructor, at `ngOnInit` and to create the var as from type `Array<MyClass>` and then call `new Array<MyClass>();`

nothing seems to work, any advice?

update: even when I comment out the `<table>` and just assigned `[]` into the var I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Show us the call to 'OnSummaryLoad'.

Comment: How is `OnSummaryLoad` invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `OnSummaryLoad` is not being considered as a Component Method. Not sure why. You might want to try the arrow function syntax. Using that should fix it:

```
public EcoSummaryList: any[] = [];

OnSummaryLoad = (data: any) => {
  this.EcoSummaryList = [];
  console.log(data);

  if (data == undefined || data == null) return;
  this.EcoSummaryList = data;

}
```